# AJAX "Access to restricted URI denied" error

Tags: ajax, jquery, jquery-plugins

I want to add jQuery modal box to my site. So, I decided to use [ColorBox plugin](http://jacklmoore.com/colorbox/).
I downloaded the source code, and tried to  open `Outside HTML (Ajax)` type  which is in example html file. But it returns this error:

```
Request unsuccessful: [Exception... "Access to restricted URI denied" code: "1012" nsresult: "0x805303f4 (NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI)" location: "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js Line: 4"]
```

But it works well in [example demo](http://jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example1/). So what can I do ?
Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**
I found the answer. The cause is I was opening the example file from `file://`, but it isn't possible to make a AJAX request from it. 
So, I runned my script with `http://` and it worked ;)

Comment: Because it doesn't show any research done. It looks like there are at least two links in the 'Related' section that are duplicates of this cross-site scripting error. The questioner didn't explain how this question is different from those, or if he'd even tried getting around cross-site scripting restrictions using any of the tips in those questions.

Comment: can you post some extra code like a snippet

Comment: I also looked these ones, but there is no answer to my question. Why it works in demo, but doesn't work in downloaded example file?

Comment: @macho you can download full plugin source code from here -> http://jacklmoore.com/colorbox/colorbox.zip

Comment: I found the answer, look the post again )